# Prove that a Higgs Bundle is Stable

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ a compact Riemann sufrace of genus $g \geq 2$, with canonical bundle $K$, and consider a line bundle $L$ s.t. $L^2=K$ and let $\omega$ a section of $K^2$.

I have an Higgs bundle $(E, \phi)$ defined by $E=L \oplus L^{-1}$ and $\phi$ given by

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \omega  \\
1 & 0  \end{array} \right)  \in H^0(X, End(E) \otimes K)
$

The notes say that this Higgs bundle is stable. How can I prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $F \subset E$ is a destabilizing. Since $\deg E = 0$ then we must have $deg F > 0$. But $\deg L^{-1} = 1 - g < 0$ so the composition $F \to L^{-1}$ must be zero. Thus $F$ is a subsheaf of $L$ but then it can't be stable under the Higgs field $\phi$ so it's not a Higgs subsheaf.

Comment: Thanks much! Why do the facts about degrees imply the triviality of the composition?

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I found the answer to my previous question: just follows form the fact that the Hom sheaf Hom(F,-L) has negative degree and hence no global sections.